# How can I customize the label of X axis, that means the label in X axis is different from the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I have a Json data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 8,
    "population": 0
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 17,
    "population": 25
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 18,
    "population": 291
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 23,
    "population": 375
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 26,
    "population": 212
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 29,
    "population": 108
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 38,
    "population": 74
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 47,
    "population": 0
  },
  {
    "year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 48,
    "population": 0
  },
```

My code now is return d.age in xScale so the labels of the X axis is the same as the data. below is the graph I have now:

[image]

However, I want  to customize my label of the x axis, I want to to be "0--8", "9--17", "18--20", "21--23", "24--26", "27--29", "30--38", "39--47", "48+" like the graph below:
[image]

Below is the code right now:

```
var margin = {top:0, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 60},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

state = {year: 2002, gender: 2};


var svg = d3.select('#main')
       .append("svg")
       .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json('./years3.json').then(years => {


var ageDomain = unique(years.map(row => row.age));
//var age = ["0--8", "9--17", "18--20", "21--23", "24--26", "27--29", "30--38", "39--47", "48+"]

//var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
            //.range([0, width])
            //.domain(age)
            //.padding(0.2);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1)
  .domain(ageDomain);



svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
   .selectAll("text")
   .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45")
   .style("text-anchor", "end");

var peopleDomain = [0, d3.max(years, row => row.population)];

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
             .range([height, 0])
             .domain(peopleDomain);

svg.append("g")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following function:

```
const getRange = d => {
    const index = ageDomain.findIndex(item => item === d);
    if(index === 0)
        return `0 -- ${d}`;
    else
        return `${ageDomain[index-1] + 1} -- ${d}`;
}
```

Then, when creating the bottom axis, add the following line

**.text(d => getRange(d))**

after

**.selectAll("text")** :

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
   .selectAll("text")
   .text(d => getRange(d))
   .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45")
   .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried it and it works but for the "18--20" is shows 18--18, and at the end I want to to be 48+ but it show 48--48, I can you give me some advice how to solve it?

Comment: for the last range, try:
if (index === ageDomain.length - 1)
    return `${d}+`;

Comment: Regarding 18--18, it happens because you have 2 consecutive values in your data (17, 18), thus 

`previous + 1 === current` 

Either merge 17 & 18 entries, or fix getRange to return 

`${d}` 

instead of 

`${ageDomain[index-1] + 1} -- ${d}` 

when 

`ageDomain[index-1] + 1=== d`

Comment: I fixed the 18-18 part. But for the 48-48 part, the last one actually is 49 and I don't know why there will be a 49 there since my data only to 48+. So I want to remove 49 and put the last one to 48+.

Comment: var getRange = d => {
    const index = ageDomain.findIndex(item => item === d);
    if (index === 0)
        return `0 - ${d}`;
    else if (index === ageDomain.length -1)
        return `${d}+`;
    else
        return `${ageDomain[index-1] + 1} - ${d}`;
} I change the code block like this but it give me "48--48, +" in the graph

Comment: I still can't figure out where dose the 49 comes from since the last number in AgeDomain is 48, and the code you provided yesterday still not solve the 48--48 problem.

Comment: @WendyHuang please send your current `getRange` function code and we will try to fix it together

Comment: here is my current getRange function: var getRange = d => {
    const index = ageDomain.findIndex(item => item === d);
    if (index === 0) {
        return `0 - ${d}`;
    }else if (index === ageDomain.length -1) {
        return `${d}+`;
    } else {
        return `${ageDomain[index-1] + 1} - ${d}`;

    }
}

Comment: @WendyHuang I run your code in a fiddle and get it perfectly correct. Please check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/x1jkfc7n/ 

I suppose you should check your data

Comment: There are not only 2002 in my dataset, there are 2003 and 2004 until 2016 and the age range is repeated in each year, do you thing this will be the reason making the code not work since the data I show here only have 2002.

Comment: I think the data is the reason, I add the 2003 data behind the 2002 data and run the code again and it didn't work. It become 48-48 at the end now. I edited it on the link you sent me, please check.  https://jsfiddle.net/k5mtLx03/

Comment: @WendyHuang you have two entries with `"age": 48`. You must either merge them into a single one or delete on of them (the entry with index 8). Your sample will not work with unordered and duplicated data.

Comment: @WendyHuang If you find original my answer useful, please upvote

Comment: I don't think I can merge them since they are different years or different genders.

Comment: @WendyHuang You can try to solve the problem by building two separate graphs for each gender. In any way your graph currently displays the age/population relation and ignores year and gender in the data.